# Box sizing: Divs appear to follow different rules from other elements

Tags: html, css

This question is related to an issue I got recently creating a `textarea` to fit a containing div. The issue itself has now come to a resolution, though I'm still interested in an answer to this question: How can one get a `textarea`'s sizing (or really, most other elements) to match that of a `div`? For a decent example, take a look at my JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/sqW73/1/

The first "pyramid" only defines the width at its outermost. The others shrink their content appropriately based on the amount of padding they've been given.

I understand that the box-sizing: border-box property would be the quickest way to accomplish what I'm looking for: `width` means the size of the content plus the size of the padding. However, my impression is that border-box is just meant to be a "quick-fix" for pages that were relying upon what people saw as IE6's broken box model. If content-box is supposed to be a reliable default, then what is the expected manner in which people should be sizing things like textboxes? Is there a separate unit type from `%` that someone could use to essentially give it the `div`'s default state?

I'm a bit pressed for time at the moment, but hopefully what I've given outlines the question in enough detail...?

Comment: content-box isn't supposed to be a reliable default, and border-box is not a quick fix for IE6. In fact, many people (http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) believe that border-box is a better default than content-box. You'll find that bootstrap 3 (for example) sets every element to box-sizing: border-box